# Removing only numbers but keep the words like "3D" in R?

Tags: r, tm

I have been coding text mining with R recently,but I have trouble dealing with data preprocessing.
I have a string like this below:

```
"I want to buy 3D printer, but it costs 3000 dollars."
```

I want keep words "3D" but remove "3000", it should be like this below:

```
"I want to buy 3D printer, but it costs dollars."
```

I use `corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)` but this will remove all the numbers in the text, so I will have the term "D printer" in the result but it should be "3D printer".

Is there any possible way to fix this probelm? Thanks!

Comment: Look for a space after the numbers `gsub("\\d+ ", "", x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
gsub('3\\d+\\s', '', str1)
```

If this needs to be general,

```
gsub('\\b\\d+\\s', '', str1)
#[1] "I want to buy 3D printer, but it costs dollars."
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a text analysis package, such as **quanteda**, which removes only numbers, not digits.  So in your case:

```
require(quanteda)
tokenize("I want to buy 3D printer, but it costs 3000 dollars.", removeNumbers = TRUE)
## tokenizedText object from 1 document.
## Component 1 :
## [1] "I"       "want"    "to"      "buy"     "3D"      "printer" ","       "but"     "it"      "costs"   "dollars" "."
```

If you want it returned as a single character object, without tokenization (although that may be your objective), then:

```
paste(tokenize("I want to buy 3D printer, but it costs 3000 dollars.",
               removeNumbers = TRUE, simplify = TRUE, removeSeparators = FALSE), 
      collapse = "")
## [1] "I want to buy 3D printer, but it costs  dollars."
```

Comment: Hi !
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175118/removing-stopwords-and-term-frequency-counting-in-r)
if you can help me with this problem, I will be grateful :)

Comment: If you edit that other post to make it clear what sort of answer you are expecting, then I will try to help. You got down votes there because your question did not make this clear.

Comment: [here are my re-edit question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282370/identifying-exact-bigram-with-tm-package-in-r)
thanks !